# Does using plughw plugin in ALSA introduce latency?

Tags: linux, audio, alsa

The plughw plugin which performs channel duplication, sample value conversion, and resampling when required.  Does this ALSA plugin introduce some latency side effects, since it does some software processing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These conversions involve some CPU processing, but it's done in real time when the samples are written to the buffer, so the latency is not affected by any noticeable amount.

Only the `dmix` plugin can delay samples, but it is not one of the plugins selected by `plug`.

Comment: Can you refer me some sources for more information on this? I having a hard time finding any.